# How fast can DirectX12 draw vertices?

Tags: parallel-processing, directx

I'm student and I'm absolutely new to DirectX, and almost new to 3D graphics - month ago I worked with three.js. But I worked really hard with WinApi and pure GDI, so, perhaps I have some knowledge.

Currently, for my diploma work, I want to model some physics process of erythrocytes. I've calculated that I will work with over 600 000 blood cells, assuming that they are cubes(although they aren't), I have 600 000 * 8 = 4 800 000 vertices. How much time will spend any powerful computer using DirectX 12 to draw that scene to buffer in memory? Is it real? By draw I mean just render one frame to buffer(not even to the screen)

I know, perhaps the question is incorrect but I'm trying to understand should I use DirectX for that purposes(I don't want to use OpenGL)

Answer (score 1):

DirectX 12 can draw vertices at exactly the same speed as DirectX 11: they both use the same drivers and hardware (assuming we are speaking of Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 11 or better hardware that actually *has* DirectX 12 driver support).

Both APIs drive the same hardware, but the difference is in how the software manages that. In DirectX 11 the runtime takes care of a lot of details on the app's behalf, but with DirectX 12 it's up to the application to do almost all of that explicitly. The result is more control (and more potential app bugs) over the behavior. This means that the total CPU overhead of drawing can be made lower on DirectX 12 than on DirectX 11.

In the end, the raw graphics performance comes down to the GPU hardware itself.

See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: You wrote the way You suppose I know something about DirectX11 but I don’t. Is a real task to draw a frame with few millions vertices today?

Comment: As with all things performance related: "it depends". With a high-end discrete GPU drawing vertices either from video RAM or using instancing and no materials/state change can draw a lot of vertices. It all depends on how efficient you can get the data to the GPU and how much money you invested in the video card.